# Unexpected token … in VSCode ESLint + Prettier

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have a node project and am using VSCode. I can't get ESLint or Prettier to work properly, they are not highlighting errors or auto-formatting code.

The only output I am getting is:

`(node:74324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: ) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`

I've been through the setup multiple times and believe I have my `.eslintrc.json` and `.prettierrc.json` set up properly. The error seems like it might be that the linters are not recognizing more modern javascript like object rest spread, but, I have experimented with adding `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to my ESLint settings file, and `"ecmaVersion": 2018`, to parserOptions, but to no avail.

Is there something I am missing to get these tools working?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem yesterday. It helped to upgrade VSCode to version 1.36.1. Than Eslint works fine.